# Why I'm getting a warning about "expected server HTML to contain a matching tag" during hydration?

Tags: next.js, onclick, tailwind-css, conditional-rendering

I'm having a hard time understanding why I get an hydration error in my server. I tried using the legacy behaviour of the `Link` component, but nothing works. I also get this error:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <a> in <ul>.
    at a
    at ul
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at nav
    at div
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./components/Header.js:24:80)
```

Is this related to conditional rendering ?

Here's the snippet, and you can see the full file at https://github.com/Adissuu/Database on the `frontend -> components -> Header`:

```jsx
<ul className="items-center justify-center space-y-8 md:flex md:space-x-6 md:space-y-0">
  <li className="text-white">
      <Link href="/signin" className=' content-center text-white hover:text-forest-200 duration-300'>
          Sign In
      </Link>
  </li>
  <li className="text-white">
      <Link href="/signup" className='btn bg-forest-100 p-1 content-center rounded-md text-white hover:bg-forest-200 duration-300'>
          Sign Up
      </Link>
  </li>

  {isAuth() && (
      <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => signout(() => Router.replace(`/signin`))}>
          Signout
      </a>
  )}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi guys, after a few hours I stumbled upon a viable solution: disable SSR for the Header. It's not a huge deal, but it helps with the conditional rendering via a function.

So in the parent of Header.js:

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Header = dynamic(() => import("./Header"), { ssr: false });

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I stumbled upon a viable solution: **disable SSR for the Header**. It's not a huge deal, but it helps with the conditional rendering via a function.

So in the parent of `Header.js`:

```ts
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Header = dynamic(() => import("./Header"), { ssr: false });
```